# Rails SQL Query return based on not being in join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I have an `Event` model. An event can have attendees through the `UserEvent` join table.

I want a query of events where a specific user id is not an attendee.

I tried `Event.joins(:user_events).where('user_events.user_id != ?', user_id)` but that clearly doesn't work because if another user attends the Event, it will still list the event because the other user's id clearly isn't equal to `user_id`. How would I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a `pluck` and a `where.not` with an `IN` query:

```
Event.where.not(id: UserEvent.where(user_id: some_user_id).pluck(:event_id))
```

This returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` which you can paginate, sort, etc.

One way to get it down to one query if you don't mind some SQL:

```
Event.where.not("id in (select event_id from user_events where user_id = #{user_id})")
```

And another single query alternative, this time using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
Event.where.not("exists (select event_id from user_events where user_id = #{user_id} and user_events.event_id = events.id)")
```